# Azure Boards: release management without Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm wondering about the wiseness of using only Azure Boards without using Azure Repos (we use another Git service) and without Azure Pipelines (our CI/CD is defined somewhere else). Specifically, I am having trouble seeing how to define releases and mark work items as belonging to a specific release, because the doc [seems to point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cross-service/end-to-end-traceability) that it would be done naturally using Azure Pipeline Builds and Releases.

I suppose we can just manually add tags to work items to specify which release they belong to, but that would mean no release dashboard/report to monitor release development.

Is it possible to use Azure Boards without handling build/deployments in Azure Pipelines without greatly reducing the usability of Azure Boards regarding release management, and how?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have researched the documentation extensively and spent countless hours looking at different configurations of DevOps. The conclusion I have drawn is _tags_ are the best solution. Especially if you are a single team sprinting multiple products, you don't want multiple sprint boards (just 1), and it seems the practice in DevOps is to leave work items in the Sprint when it's over (sprint 1, 2, 3 etc), so organizing by release tags is the only real option. Organizing by releases using iterations means you have to have 1 running sprint and move work items out

Answer (score 1):

##### Option 1 - integrations

This depends on the specific service you use. For example, you can use Azure DevOps Boards and GitHub repo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/?view=azure-devops.
However, the number of integrations is quite limited.

##### Option 2 - calling DevOps API

Tag the work items by calling the Azure DevOps API in your pipelines (wherever the pipelines are running, as long as they can call an API). E.g. to update tag on a work item:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/tags/18090594-b371-4140-99d2-fc93bcbcddec?api-version=6.0-preview.1

{
  "id": "18090594-b371-4140-99d2-fc93bcbcddec",
  "name": "my-first-tag",
  "url": "http://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/tags/18090594-b371-4140-99d2-fc93bcbcddec?api-version=5.1-preview"
}
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/tags/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP